# Cannot Write Graph with attributes in graphml format in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graphml

I am trying to export my directed graph into graphml format in networkx. here is the graph code in networkx and the error i am getting:

```
h = nx.path_graph(5)

G.add_nodes_from(h)

G.add_edges_from(h.edges()

G[0]['name']="panama"

G[1]['name']="costa rica"

G[2]['name']="Argentina"

G[3]['name']="Brazil"

G[4]['name']="Coloumbia"

G[1][2]['connection']='road'

nx.write_graphml(G,"te.graphml")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in write_graphml
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 220, in _open_file
    result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/graphml.py", line 82, in write_graphml
    writer.add_graph_element(G)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/graphml.py", line 351, in add_graph_element
    self.add_edges(G,graph_element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/graphml.py", line 325, in add_edges
    self.add_attributes("edge", edge_element, data, default)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/graphml.py", line 297, in add_attributes
    for k,v in data.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to make assignments to arbitrary internal NetworkX data structures but in this case you are doing the assignment incorrectly (and it breaks the data structure).

You have

```
h = nx.path_graph(5)
G.add_nodes_from(h)
G.add_edges_from(h.edges()
G[0]['name']="panama" <--- this corrupts the adjacency data structure
```

use

```
G.node[0]['name']='panama'
```

to assign data to nodes.